# Pointwise limit of $f_n(x) =x^2 - \frac{x^n}{n}$

Tags: limits

I want to find the (pointwise) limit of $f_n = x^2 - \frac{x^n}{n}$. So, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x^2 - \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{n}$. I know that the latter is limit $0$ if $|x|<1$, but otherwise it is $\infty$. So what should I say about the pointwise limit of $f_n$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \Rightarrow f(\pm 1) = 1, f(x) = x^2, |x| < 1 \to f(x) = \begin{cases} 1&: x = \pm 1 \\  x^2&: |x| < 1 \\ \text{does not exist}&: |x| > 1\end{cases}$